# Cancel unsaved changes without closing the files

Tags: visual-studio-code

Case:
1. Open a file.
2. Make some changes.
3. Cancel all the unsaved changes at once without closing the file.

Is it possible to achieve this in VS Code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I undo, unsaved changes in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55131389/how-can-i-undo-unsaved-changes-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 8):

### **Silly way:**

1. File.
2. Revert Changes.

### **Using shortcuts:**

1. Click on the **cog** in the bottom-right corner.
2. Keyboard shortcuts.
3. Search for `workbench.actions.file.revert`.
4. Assign the appropriate shortcut.
5. Use the shortcut whenever needed.