# How can I undo, unsaved changes in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, undo

Are there any shortcuts that allows a user to undo changes(similar to `command+z`) but back to when the file was last saved? I'm currently getting this done by closing files, discarding changes, and reopening them but this is tedious. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cancel unsaved changes without closing the files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024999/cancel-unsaved-changes-without-closing-the-files)

Answer (score 31):

In the top left menu:

**File** > **Revert File**

On mac this does not have a shortcut assigned per default. You will have to assign a shortcut yourself.